# Aspell error: no suitable spell-checker program found

Tags: r, installation, aspell

Although  the function `aspell` comes standard with the `utils` package, it doesn't seem to work for me. I keep on getting the same error:

```
aspell("love")
Error in aspell("love") : No suitable spell-checker program found
```

Any thoughts?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Belgium.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Belgium.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Belgium.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: My first thought is: please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) show us the code you have tried. Thanks!

Comment: just the usual examples, with one word

Comment: You don't even tell us what operating system you're using, which seems quite relevant for your question.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, the function `aspell("love")` is improper. Please reference the correct function call at [inside-r.org](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/aspell). This is, however, not your big obstacle. The reason you are getting the `No suitable spell-checker program found` error is because, as you and @juba have hinted to here, your installation of aspell() is lacking. Please consider the following for proper installation.

**Step 1.** Download Aspell Win32 from following link (Yes, it's ancient)
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/w32/Aspell-0-50-3-3-Setup.exe

**Step 2.** Install Aspell Win32 in Appdata roaming folder (it may be convenient to create a SpellCheckers parent folder before hand)
[image]

**Step 3.** Add Aspell Win32 to the Windows PATH. [Learn how to add variables to your system path](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). In our example, type
`C:\Users\UrPC\AppData\Roaming\SpellCheckers\Aspell\bin\`, where **UrPC** is the name of your PC.

**Step 4.** Confirm this environment variable edit by clicking OK several times and exiting the advanced systems property dialogue,

**Step 5.** Download Aspell dictionary from following link (I don't believe newer versions will work but who knows)
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/w32/Aspell-en-0.50-2-3.exe

**Step 6.** In any directory run the Aspell dictionary 'installer' and it will unpack itself to a folder called `TmpInstall` in the same directory.

**Step 7.** Open the `TmpInstall` folder and run setup-Aspell-en-0.50-2.exe. It should auto detect where your Aspell Win32 installation is based on the system path we added in Step 3. If not, proceed to Step 8.

**Step 8.** Open windows PowerShell and type the word `aspell`

You should see command information vomit down your prompt. If you don't you may have entered the PATH information incorrectly (and need to fix it) or need to restart Windows. If after doing this you still throw an error, consider the Appendix.

**Appendix:** If Aspell was previously uninstalled you may need to delete it's orphaned registry key. Run regedit.exe and search for aspell. Delete any aspell key associated with an uninstalled aspell directory. Be very careful not to unintentionally change anything other than the aspell key in question as deleting something by accident could send you to Windows Hell.

This wisdom is an extension of the procedure to [install Hunspell on Windows](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2014-04/msg00030.html)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the `aspell` [help page](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/functions/aspell) ?

If you read it, you will discover the `program` argument :

> **program** a character string giving the name (if on the system path) or
>   full path of the spell check program to be used, or NULL (default). By
>   default, the system path is searched for aspell, hunspell and ispell
>   (in that order), and the first one found is used.

And you will also read the following in the *Details* section :

> The spell check programs employed must support the so-called Ispell
>   pipe interface activated via command line option -a. In addition to
>   the programs, suitable dictionaries need to be available. See
>   http://aspell.net, http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/ and
>   http://lasr.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell.html, respectively, for obtaining
>   the Aspell, Hunspell and (International) Ispell programs and
>   dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me to find some useful dictionary's, which i can load as (word)library's. Installing aspel hunspell on win7 still looks like a mystery tho.