# How to use Aspell in R?

Tags: r, macos, installation, spell-checking, aspell

Before I used Aspell, I had installed aspell and english dictionary in terminal (OS X 10.9) . When I tried `> aspell("duncan")` as exemplified by *http://www.omegahat.org/Aspell/aspell.html*, console showed:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open file 'duncan': No such file or directory
```

I thought it might because aspell{utils} might be different from aspell of Aspell package. Then I tried to install Aspell by `install.packages("Aspell", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")` based on *http://www.omegahat.org/Aspell/* but R showed:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/macosx/contrib/3.1

   package ‘Aspell’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning message:
package ‘Aspell’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

In addition, I am totally confused by `R CMD INSTALL Aspell_0.1-0.tar.gz`(*http://www.omegahat.org/Aspell/*). Where should I type and run it?

How can I use Aspell in R normally? Or can your provide me a good manual?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at this question and answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093319/aspell-error-no-suitable-spell-checker-program-found

Comment: @lawyeR Yes, I've read it before. But I think I am asking a different question. The page you mentioned is because the user did not install "aspell" in operation system. Mine is about how to install aspell in R. And I've tried `> files <- Sys.glob("*.Rd")
> files
character(0)` mentioned in *http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/functions/aspell* but nothing works.

Comment: Does `install.packages("Aspell", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")` work?

Comment: @KarstenW. Yes! It works well! Thank you so much! One more thing, when I run it on windows on school's PC it shows      `Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/Users/c1268298/Desktop/Apps/R/R-3.1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\c1268298\Desktop\Apps\R\R-3.1.1\library" C:\Users\c1268298\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGAFX2h/downloaded_packages/Aspell_0.2-0.tar.gz' had status 1 `.

Comment: I believe the package contains a C library. Hence you need [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to compile it on windows.

Comment: @KarstenW. Thank you so much and you do help me a lot! What should I read or what should I do if I want to be someone like you.

Comment: You sure don't want be like me. But thanks for the flattering anyhow. You're welcome!