# installing Aspell and R

Tags: r, rstudio, spell-checking, aspell

I've installed Aspell where I get a desktop icon-as in I can drag and drop text files in it and the spell check works as expected. However, when I try using the aspell function in Rstudio, I get this as a message: No suitable spell-checker program found. I am unsure of the steps I need to take to remedy this so R picks up on the fact I've installed Aspell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am now getting this as my error

Error in aspell(visit1total) : Running aspell failed with diagnostics:
Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".

Again, I would appreciate any help anyone can offer. I am using Windows 7. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have added the `rstudio` tag. Please also state which OS you are using, as that might be important.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate the first answer from:

https://superuser.com/questions/601928/how-do-i-add-missing-dictionaries-for-aspell

Download and untar the latest english dictionary (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/en/ - currently v7.1.0):

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/en/aspell6-en-7.1-0.tar.bz2
tar xvjf aspell6-en-7.1-0.tar.bz2
```

Then follow the README to install as follows:

```
cd aspell6-en-7.1-0/
./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with not having fully configured Aspell for use on Windows. Consider reviewing my post on [performing a full installation of aspell on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093319/aspell-error-no-suitable-spell-checker-program-found/29056341#29056341)